# singlethreadexecutor - Multuthreading java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, operating-system

When should one use singleThreadExecutor in java? Also, when should one use cachedThreadpool?
It is specified both in documentations and books that singleThreadExecutor is preferred over fixedThreadPool(1) as it would not let modification in the number of threads like the latter, but what are the scenarios in which it is advisable or use singleThreadExecutor

Comment: When you want to execute things on one thread?

Answer (score 1):

`newSingleThreadExecutor()` is good when you know that one additional thread doing jobs in background is enough in your case (means there wouldn't be lots of jobs waiting in queue). And you don't need/want to extend `Thread` or implement `Runnable` and do all job transferring stuff by yourself. `Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially` - this also may be usefull, if you know that parallel task execution may cause deadlock or data race.

`cachedThreadpool()` - just look into source code

```
public static ExecutorService newCachedThreadPool() {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                                  60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                                  new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
}
```

it creates new thread on demand and keeps them idle for no longer then 1 minute.  And as it's said in docs

> .. These pools will typically improve the performance of programs that
>   execute many short-lived asynchronous tasks. Calls to execute
>   will reuse previously constructed threads if available. If no existing
>   thread is available, a new thread will be created and added to the
>   pool. ..

But there is no upper bound for number of threads, so I would prefer to construct pool by hands with `maximumPoolSize` much fewer than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, e.g. 128.